# how to save audio file in recorder.js on server

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Using recorder.js we can download recorded audio file using forceDownload. How can I save this  audio file on server so that I can use it when required.

Answer (score 1):

Recorder.JS provides an exportWAV() function, which will give the callback a Blob containing the audio. You can then use XmlHttpRequest to send the blob to your server as a standard post request.

```
recorder.stop();
recorder.exportWAV(function(audio) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "audio/wav");
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        // Handle the response.
    }
    xhr.send(audio);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [RecordRTC-to-PHP](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/PHP/).

[RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) is a library sits top of RecorderJs; provides recording of both audio and video streams, both on chrome and firefox.

See server side [PHP code](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP#php-code); along with javascript implementation.

Comment: what about browser compatability?

Comment: RecordRTC can record audio both on chrome, firefox and opera; video on chrome/opera only because webp seems not supported on firefox. Gif recording supported on all three browsers. Audio recording seems not working on android out of WebAudio implementation.

Comment: @MuazKhan Audio does not recorded! I could see only a video. There is no wav to play.

Comment: Hi, @Mr.Hyde, This issue has been fixed. Regards.